# failed to load image from cloudinary in heroku. Got an error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

Tags: cloudinary

In the process of deploying MERN project, i got an error saying **net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200**. Where i want to load or fetch image from cloudinary and display but i got this error.

my console looks like:
[a picture of console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arEOy.png)

The request header in my network tab looks like: [request header screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7yG1.png)

The response header in my network tab looks like: [response header screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XECyn.png)

i tried to set the header as shown in the response header screenshoot but still gettint an error:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", " true");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://gadgetinfo-mern-stack.herokuapp.com",
    "http://127.0.0.1:800",
    " https://res.cloudinary.com/"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy", "cross-origin");
  next();
});
```

If anyone knows how to get rid of the problem please help.
anything or any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see the error you get is "net:: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200"

Would you try swapping to this header?

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

If this does not resolve the issue, please submit a ticket at http://support.cloudinary.com and we will take a deeper look.

Comment: i tried using res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") and still am getting the same error. And you mean submit a ticket at cloudinary is to submit a request at cloudinary explaining the error i am getting?

Comment: Hey, yah exactly.